# max_old_space_size set to 4gb, actually limits to 2GB

Tags: node.js, memory-limit

I'm writing a NodeJS 6.3.1 application under Gentoo Linux 64 bit.
In this machine I generally have 9GB out of 16GB free memory and 49GB swap space barely used.

I use the following code to the test the memory limit of my node.js application:

```
var arr = []; 
var c=0;
while(arr.push('foo')) {if (++c%100000 == 0) {console.info(process.memoryUsage());}}
```

Running this script with no extra parameters to node, the last memoryUsage line is this:

```
{ rss: 1032232960, heapTotal: 1015185408, heapUsed: 1008680024 }
```

Now running node.js with `--max_old_space_size=4096`, the last memoryUsage line is this:

```
{ rss: 2202341376, heapTotal: 2189082624, heapUsed: 2177311480 }
```

now with 8000 limit:

```
{ rss: 1934946304, heapTotal: 1921712128, heapUsed: 1909919344 }
```

What am I missing? How can I increase the heap to 4 or 8GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a limitation of V8. It does not use more than 1.7 GB of RAM on 64 bit machines. Quote from FAQ:

> Currently, by default v8 has a memory limit of 512mb on 32-bit
>   systems, and 1gb on 64-bit systems. The limit can be raised by setting
>   --max-old-space-size to a maximum of ~1gb (32-bit) and ~1.7gb (64-bit), but it is recommended that you split your single process
>   into several workers if you are hitting memory limits.

Comment: thanks. what this always the case? many tutorials online shows that they increased their max old space size to 4GB or 8GB.